# How to load settings dictionary from appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have some database settings in my appsettings.json file.  This system connects to different databases in production there are 60+ of them.

Each customer has an internal number in our system and their database has a connection string.

What I am trying to do is load these settings, so that I can validate that they are working at startup / health check.  I have a method which is called from ConfigureServices.  It takes IConfiguration configuration as a parameter.

```
"KommuneConfiguration": {
    "localhost": {
      "KommuneNumber": "localhost",
      "ConnectionString": "Server=H52371;Database=DeliveryReport;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
      "TableName": "[DeliveryReport].[dbo].[DeliveryReport]"
    },
    "000": {
      "KommuneNumber": "000",
      "ConnectionString": "Server=172.31.112.106;Database=000_XXXX_02_EDW;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
      "TableName": "[000_XXXX_02_EDW].[gateway].[DeliveryReport]"
    },
    "550": {
      "KommuneNumber": "550",
      "ConnectionString": "Server=172.31.112.106;Database=550_XXXX_02_EDW;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
      "TableName": "[550_XXXX_02_EDW].[gateway].[DeliveryReport]"
    },
    "607": {
      "KommuneNumber": "607",
      "ConnectionString": "Server=172.31.112.106;Database=607_XXXX_02_EDW;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
      "TableName": "[607_XXXX_02_EDW].[gateway].[DeliveryReport]"
    }
  },
```

## what I have tried.

This seams to load the first level IE they key but the object value is null

```
var serviceClientSettingsConfigKommune = configuration.GetSection("KommuneConfiguration").GetChildren()
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

This just loads null

```
  var hold = new KommuneSettings();
  configuration.GetSection("KommuneConfiguration").Bind(hold);
```

This does the same as the first one did it loads the key but the value is null.

```
var serviceClientSettingsConfigKommune = configuration.GetSection("KommuneConfiguration").Get<Dictionary<string, KommuneConfiguration>>();
```

These are the objects I have been testing with.

```
public class KommuneConfiguration
    {
        public string KommuneNumber { get; set; }
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }

 public class KommuneSettings
    {
        public Dictionary<string,KommuneConfiguration> Settings { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way -

```
var serviceClientSettingsConfigKommune = configuration.GetSection("KommuneConfiguration").Get<List<KommuneConfiguration>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed Settings in your config

`````
"KommuneConfiguration": { 
"Settings" :{
    "localhost": {
      "KommuneNumber": "localhost",
      "ConnectionString": "Server=H52371;Database=DeliveryReport;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
      "TableName": "[DeliveryReport].[dbo].[DeliveryReport]"
    },
    "000": {
      "KommuneNumber": "000",
      "ConnectionString": "Server=172.31.112.106;Database=000_XXXX_02_EDW;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
      "TableName": "[000_XXXX_02_EDW].[gateway].[DeliveryReport]"
    },
    "550": {
      "KommuneNumber": "550",
      "ConnectionString": "Server=172.31.112.106;Database=550_XXXX_02_EDW;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
      "TableName": "[550_XXXX_02_EDW].[gateway].[DeliveryReport]"
    },
    "607": {
      "KommuneNumber": "607",
      "ConnectionString": "Server=172.31.112.106;Database=607_XXXX_02_EDW;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
      "TableName": "[607_XXXX_02_EDW].[gateway].[DeliveryReport]"
    }
  }},````
`````